# While Using the NLP for my work One Bag of Word is been used by two Levels as a result assigning to Single Level. How to Overcome this Problem?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have two messages in an example to to do the NLP and they are been distinguish on the different label and the bag of word taken is "Revisit " for both the messages.

For the first one its predicting correctly and message is been directly predicted the same as its label whereas for the second one its taking "Revisit " as its bag of word and instead of going to label "BH" its been direct to label "Hardware".

How to get it solved?

[image]

Comment: I think we need more details to find out what went wrong.. for example what is you're trying to do?? classification? or Information Extraction? or Both? How did you trained this model?? What the training data look like? What is the size of the data?

Comment: Hi Anwaric,
Please find below the answer to following question.
classification? or Information Extraction?- Both
How did you trained this model- By the Naive Bayes model.
What is the size of the data:- 5500 rows and 4 columns.